# Error al compilar usando ionic build android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación hibrida usando ***ionic framework***, pero empece a notar unos errores al visualizar las vistas en chrome, era que no me dejo reflejar mas cambios realizados a nivel de codigo en las vistas; entonces me pase a firefox developer edition, y funciono todo perfecto.

El problema vino ayer que compile usando ***ionic build android*** para obtener la apk e instalarla, se instalo normal pero los estilos no cargan junto con la aplicación, y el mismo error de las vistas que no me redireccionaba en chrome me aparece luego de compilar.

Aclaro que en ***firefox developer edition*** y ***ionic*** lab no ocurren estos errores, estoy usando flexbox, si ionic no soporta esto agradeceria que alguien me ayudara. Dejo por aqui la vista login y como se refleja en este caso la no carga del fichero ***CSS***.

[image: Navegador]

[image: Ionic Lab]

[image: Android device]

Comment: ¿Cuáles son estos errores de los que hablas?, ¿los puedes incluir en tu pregunta?

Comment: 1- Los estilos que pongo usando css no se ven reflejados en la version compilada
2 - Las animaciones, en este caso spinners, no aparecen.
3 - Por mucho que modifique quite o agrgue algo nuevo, si utilizo chrome, esto no se ve reflejado, pero en firefox developer edition si
4 - La configuracion de route tampoco funciona en chrome, por ejemplo si le doy en chrome click a la opcion perfil me envia a la vista login, pero si lo hago en firefox DE, si funciona

Si tienes alguna solucion te lo agradceria, estoy pasando el codigo para por parte a ver donde surge el problema

Comment: Disculpa ya solucione lo del css, estaba poniendo unos puntos y comas donde no debian ir, de igual forma solo me queda arreglar lo de routing de todos modos gracias

Comment: Bueno corregi los errores en el navegador y el ionic lab, pero al compilar siguen apareciendo los mismos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que el webview de cada versión de Android es diferente, prueba si tu webapp funciona con el navegador nativo del dispositivo, si no se ve correctamente es porque el CSS que intentas usar no lo soporta.
No ser si conoces Framework7, que está mejor optimizado para apps híbridas.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, agregue Crosswalk a la aplicacion y listo, funciona, lo que sucede es que flexbox segun lei, solo funciona por decir de forma "nativa", lo pongo entre comillas por es una forma de decirlo en android 4.4 o superior @Webserveis

Answer (score 2):

Igual si estas manejando **ionic** que es una muy buena opción puedes solucionar este error de las versiones de cada dispositvo con https://crosswalk-project.org/.

Esto lo soluciona el problema, ademas que aumenta el performance de tu app, para instalarlo en tu proyecto solo tienes que ejecutar:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Despues de esto puedes volver a compilar tu app y te funcionara correctamente.

Comment: Si eso hice, gracias de igual forma