# Como borrar el historial de navegacion en ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Hola comunidad tenga una duda acerca del uso de ***$ionicHistory*** que hace parte de las extensión ***Navigation*** de las extensiones javascript/angular.

Quisiera saber como evitar volver atrás cuando este en uno de los dos menus, dependiendo del rol del usuario que halla ingresado.

[image: estructura de la app]

Quisiera resolver las siguientes inquietudes

1. Solo puede dar al botón de atrás si la vista no es la del menú (sea estudiante o profesor)
2. En el caso de android, existe el botón atrás, sea físico o digital, si esta en la vista o template de cualquiera de los dos menús, entonces, al dar atras, debe salir de la aplicacion
3. Evitar que guarde rutas o vistas en este historial, para evitar conflictos en un futuro.

Comment: Creo que deberías postear código relevante de tu aplicacion para que esta pueda ser más util a los futuros lectores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema puede resolverse usando el método `clearHistory()` del servicio `$ionicHistory` tanto en tu controller de la vista estudiante o profesor puedes llamar a ese método y esto evitará que se pueda navegar hacia atrás ya que ese método elimina el historial excepto la vista actual(por eso es necesario que lo hagas en la vista del estudiante o profesor).

```
...
.controller('EstudianteCtrl', function($ionicHistory) {
    ...
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
});
```

También puedes usar el método `nextViewOptions()` y desabilitar el botón atrás de esta forma

```
 $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
     disableBack: true // Esto pone en `null` la vista anterior
 });
```

Pero esto debes hacerlo desde la vista anterior(La vista "cargando") ya que eso aplica a la próxima vista a mostrar antes de transicionar a ella.

Por último para hacer que tu aplicacion salga al presionar el boton back tienes que usar el servicio `$ionicPlatform` usando `onHardwareBackButton` pero te estas adentrando inadvertidamente en un problema:

1. Si sales de tu aplicación al hacer back corres el riesgo que tus usuarios salgan de la aplicación sin quererlo, sobre todo si tienes muchas vistas en profundidad en tu navegación. Atrás..., Atrás..., Atrás..., Salir...Ups!!!
2. La mayoría de las aplicaciones móviles implementan una forma de salir al llegar a la vista del home usando el botón back lo cual se ha convertido practicamente en un standard.
3. Tu quieres mantener a los usuarios dentro de tu aplicación y no fuera de ella ;)

La solución que yo le veo a eso es usar **dos** pulsaciones back en lugar de una mostrando un toast con un mensaje con algo así como "Presione nuevamente para salir"

El toast lo puedes instalar con un plugin que puedes encontrar en https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin usando

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast
```

Luego en el evento `platformReady` estableces el evento(para asegurarse de que el plugin haya cargado)

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    var closeApp = false;
    $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function () {
            if ($state.is('mivistaraiz')) {
                if (closeApp === true) {
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else {
                    closeApp = true;
                    $timeout(function () {
                        closeApp = false;
                    }, 2000);
                    notifications.notify("Presione nuevamente para salir", "short", "bottom");
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Puedes cambiar el timeout para que sea más grande pero básicamente lo que hace es salir si se presiona el back en un intervalo de 2 segundos sino vuelve a mostrar el toast, evitando así que tus usuarios salgan de la aplicación por accidente.

Comment: Ok , gracias, probare, y te comentare, que tal me fue

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Revisa mi update. Tuve que ausentarme un momento y no pude publicar mi respuesta completa de una sola vez pero ahí la tienes espero que te sirva.

Comment: ok, gracias, disculpa hice esta pregunta la otra vez, pero nadie me ha dado una respuesta, te dejo esto por aqui no se si tu sepas que podria causar el que no salgan los estilos usando flexbox http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5497/error-al-compilar-usando-ionic-build-android

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Lo que pasa con esa pregunta es lo mismo que pasa con esta. Cuando haces una pregunta tienes que poner código relevante ya que la comunidad lo primero que intenta es reproducir tu error; si solo incluyes fotos esto ya no es posible. Lee que es un [emcv o mvce en inglés](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Es por eso que la pregunta tiene tantos votos de cierre. Dices que tienes errores pero no muestras cuales son. Creo que ese es el primer paso para conseguir ayuda. Esta pregunta tenía una solución obvia por eso tuviste mas suerte. Saludos.

Comment: edite la pregunta, si puedes echarle un ojo a el código que puse te lo agradeceria

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Je lo que hiciste fue copiar mi respuesta a tu pregunta. Creo que deberías editarla nuevamente removiendo esas partes y asi queda el registro como debe ser ya que las personas que lean van a pensar que nunca tuviste ningún problema en primer lugar ;)

Comment: ya agregue el codigo como lo estoy tratando de agregar y configurar a mi aplicacion, espero una respuesta

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Creo que no entendiste. Debes respetar la pregunta original para que les sirva a otros como tu que vienen buscando ayuda al sitio. Si necesitas mas ayuda puedes abrir una nueva pregunta o con gusto podría hacerlo por chat.

Comment: Gracias @devconcept, ya lo hago